# Multiple UITabBarControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to make an App that has multiple UITabBarControllers. The idea is that when the app launches, the user has 3 options, and based on what option he chooses decides which UITabBarController is displayed. (i have kinda got this bit working atm). BUT i want the user to be able to go back to the beginning and choose another option, again displaying a different UITabBarController. - this is where i am stuck

can anyone help me? or suggest the best way to handle this.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose a UINavigationController to be the rootViewController of the window object.

The first UIViewController shows the options for the three tab bars. Depending on the selection you can push a specific UITabbarController to the UINavigationController. May this idea help?

Comment: Agreed - UINavigationController is the easiest way to create a flow hierarchy like described